# Logic Pro X Midi FX Javascript - Using GetTimingInfo() causes 100% CPU

Tags: javascript, midi

I'm using the Scripter MidiFX in MainStage 3 (same as LogicPro X) to create a custom arpeggiator with javascript since I needed more control, so it seemed logical to use GetTimingInfo() to get the current beat inside of the ProcessMIDI() function to trigger the MIDI notes, as I saw in their examples.  Unfortunately this pegs the CPU even on my Core i7 MacBook Pro, and I'm using a MacMini with a Core 2 Duo processor at actual shows.

I was able to write my own code to calculate the current beat using new Date() and then only using GetTimingInfo() to get the current tempo when a new note is pressed, but even that wasn't keeping the CPU where I'd like it to be.

When I don't include "NeedsTimingInfo=true" and just hard code the tempo everything works great, but this is a lot of extra code and makes more sense to use the built in functions.

Here's a simple sequencer example that causes this problem... am I doing something wrong?  This happen even if I use a counter only run ProcessMIDI() on every 16th call!

```
NeedsTimingInfo = true;

var startBeat = -1;
var startPitch = 0;
var lastBeat = -1;
var currentStep = 0;

// melody test
var steps = [
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5
];

function HandleMIDI(e) {
    if (e instanceof NoteOn) {
        if (startBeat > 0) return;

        currentStep = 0;
        startPitch = e.pitch;
        var info = GetTimingInfo();
        lastBeat = startBeat = info.blockStartBeat; 
        doNote(e.pitch);
    }
    else if (e instanceof NoteOff) {
        if (e.pitch == startPitch) {
            startBeat = -1;
        }
    }
    else {
        e.send();
    }
}

function doNote(pitch) {
    var adjustment = 0;
    if (currentStep < steps.length) {
        adjustment = steps[currentStep];
    }
    var p = pitch + adjustment;

    var on = new NoteOn;
    on.pitch = p;
    on.send();
    var off = new NoteOff;
    off.pitch = p;
    off.sendAfterBeats(0.9);    
}

function ProcessMIDI() {
    var info = GetTimingInfo();
    if (!info.playing) return;
    if (startBeat < 0) return;
    var beat = info.blockStartBeat;
    if (beat - lastBeat >= 1) {
        currentStep++;
        doNote(startPitch);
        lastBeat = beat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your I/O Buffer Size set to in Preferences>Audio>Advanced Settings ? The smaller the buffer size, the more CPU is required. I assume that since you are using MainStage for live use, you have a very low setting to minimize your latency.

I tried running your code with a buffer size of 16, and MS stuttered and maxed out the CPU. 64 handled it better (the CPU meter spiked, but played without any hiccups). Tested on a 2009 MacBook Pro 3.06 Core 2 Duo.

You may have to live with a little more latency in order for Scripter to run smoothly. Your code itself, is solid.

Comment: I had sputters with the maximum buffer size even... I usually run at 512 but increased to 1024 and still not enough.  Strangely enough, it happened less when changing the setting to use a single core.  This problem went away downgrading to MainStage 3.0.3 from 3.0.4

Comment: I'm curious what version you tested on.

Comment: I tested on 3.0.4 without the problems you describe. Sorry that this is happening; I don't know if there is much else I can add at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The issue went away with MainStage 3.0.3, which I was able to find using TimeMachine.

I did create a custom Javascript implementation of their timing for 3.0.4, which did help quite a bit, but is an extra 100 lines or so of code (below).  If anyone else runs into this problem, I would suggest the downgrade instead.

```
/**---[lib/TimingInfo.js]---*/
/**
  * Constructor accepts the tempo for beat syncing and starts the clock
  * to the current time.
  *
  * @param tempo the tempo of the song (default: 120bpm)
  */
function TimingInfo(tempo) {    
    this.schedule = [];
    this.setTempo(tempo);
    this.reset();
}
/** 
  * Sets the tempo and computes all times associated, assuming a 4/4
  * beat structure.
  * 
  * @param tempo the current tempo in beats per minute.
  */
TimingInfo.prototype.setTempo = function(tempo) {
    this.tempo = tempo || 120;      
    this.msecPerBeat = (60 / this.tempo) * 1000;
};
/**
  * Resets the beatsync to be relative to the current time.
  */
TimingInfo.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.startTime = new Date().getTime();
    this.update();
    // trigger all scheduled messages immediately.  TODO: note off only?
    this._sendScheduled(null);
};
/**
  * Uses the current time to update what the current beat is and all
  * related properties.  Any scheduled actions are performed if their
  * time has passed.
  */
TimingInfo.prototype.update = function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    this.elapsedMsec = now - this.startTime;
    this.beat = this.elapsedMsec / this.msecPerBeat;
    this._sendScheduled(this.beat); 
};
/**
  * Schedules a midi message to be sent at a specific beat.
  * @param e MIDI event to schedule
  * @param beat the beat number to send it on
  */
TimingInfo.prototype.sendAtBeat = function(e, beat) {
    if (e == null) return;
    // insert in-order into schedule
    var insertAt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.schedule.length; i++) {
        if (this.schedule[i].beat > beat) {
            insertAt = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    this.schedule.splice(insertAt, 0, {e:e, beat:beat});
};
/**
  * Schedules a midi message relative to current beat.
  */
TimingInfo.prototype.sendAfterBeats = function(e, deltaBeats) {
    this.sendAtBeat(e, this.beat + deltaBeats);
};
/**
  * Sends all messages scheduled on or before a given beat.  If not
  * supplied all scheduled items are sent.
  *
  * @param atBeat beat to compare all scheduled events against (default: all)
  */ 
TimingInfo.prototype._sendScheduled = function(atBeat) {
    // send all items on or before the given beat
    var sent = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.schedule.length; i++) {
        if (!atBeat || this.schedule[i].beat <= atBeat) {
            this.schedule[i].e.send();
            sent++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    // remove sent items
    this.schedule.splice(0, sent);
};

var _timing = null;
/**
  * Replacement for GetTimingInfo() that calls update() to handling 
  * any scheduled actions.
  */
function GetNewTimingInfo() {
    if (_timing == null) {
        _timing = new TimingInfo();
    }
    _timing.update();
    return _timing;
}
```